# Convert pixel offset back to value and vice versa

Tags: d3.js

I'm loading some external data with d3.js. I managed to render this data at the correct position in my plot. Using drag and drop I update the position of the object. Now I want to convert this position back to the corresponding value on the y-axis, but I have no clue how to do this.

Data.csv:

```
date,value
2017-02-02,30.5
```

Data loading:

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
    if (error) throw error;

    // format the data
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseTime(d.date);
        d.value = +d.value;
    });


    dataPoints = data;

});
```

Scales

```
self.x = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain([new Date(2017, 1, 1), new Date(2017, 1, 14)])
    .range([0, self.size.width]);


self.y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([self.options.ymin, self.options.ymax])
    .range([self.size.height, 0]);
```

Updating position of objects:

```
svg.selectAll('circle')
    .data(dataPoints)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('r', 7)
    .attr('cx', function (d) {
        return self.x(d.date);
    })
    .attr("cy", function (d) {
        return self.y(d.value);
    })
    .call(d3.drag().on('drag', function(d) {
        d3.select(this).attr('cy', d.y = d3.event.y);
    }));
```

Zooming function

```
var transform = d3.event.transform;

var xNewScale = transform.rescaleX(this.x);
this.gX.call(this.xAxis.scale(xNewScale));

var yNewScale = transform.rescaleY(this.y);
this.gY.call(this.yAxis.scale(yNewScale));

svg.selectAll('circle')
    .attr('cx', function (d) {
        return transform.applyX(self.x(d.date));
    })
    .attr('cy', function (d) {
        return transform.applyY(self.y(d.value));
    });
```

**Solved!**

I changed this :

Updating position of objects:

```
svg.selectAll('circle')
    .data(dataPoints)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('r', 7)
    .attr('cx', function (d) {
        return self.x(d.date);
    })
    .attr("cy", function (d) {
        return self.y(d.value);
    })
    .call(d3.drag().on('drag', function(d) {
        d3.select(this).attr('cy', d.y = d3.event.y);
    }));
```

to this :

```
svg.selectAll('circle')
    .data(dataPoints)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('r', 7)
    .attr('cx', function (d) {
        return self.x(d.date);
    })
    .attr("cy", function (d) {
        return self.y(d.value);
    })
    .call(d3.drag().on('drag', function(d) {
        d.value = self.y.invert(d3.event.y);
        d3.select(this).attr('cy', self.y(d.value));
    }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the corresponding value of the new position in the y axis, you have to use [invert](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#continuous_invert):

> Given a value from the range, returns the corresponding value from the domain. Inversion is useful for interaction, say to determine the data value corresponding to the position of the mouse

So, for instance:

```js
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 10])
  .range([0, 500]);
  
console.log(y.invert(350));
console.log(y.invert(40));
console.log(y.invert(500));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works like a charm. I updated the question.